# What is the API in sonos which developers can use to play/pause/stop music

Tags: sonos

I was going through the documentation and was looking for the API's which i can call from a console application to play/pause or stop music. I am assuming Sonos is like Philips Hue which requires the devices to be in the same local network.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[Sonos API](http://musicpartners.sonos-ws-us.com/?q=docs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no supported way to do this, but it is something that we are working creating an API to do.

People have created libraries for this type of integration that can be found with a quick Google search, but none of these are supported by Sonos and there is no guarantee of future compatibility.

Comment: Do you have any idea of release dates? Will this api be available through the cloud or only locally?

Answer (score 0):

See the UPnP specification for AVTransport, and use the Play/Pause APIs on the coordinating Player. And yes, for UPnP you need to be on the same network as the players.